# Removing multiple slashes with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know how to do it with PHP, how to replace multiple slashes from URL to only one, for example:

```
http://example.com/uri1////////uri2/uri4
```

replace to:

```
http://example.com/uri1/uri2/uri4
```

etc. How do to it with htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Its kind good but it replaces all to two slashes, for ex. `http://address.com////////////////////////uri` to `http://address.com//uri`