# capture first value of group RegEx

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In order to disallow multiple language folder repetition in my website `http://domain.com/en/fr/es/` I set the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){2,}(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

It's working nice but my problem is that the first captured group return `es`, but I'd like to get the first language folder `en`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/)(?:[a-z]{2}/)+(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=302,L]
```

Problem in your pattern is that `([a-z]{2}/){2,}` matches all of `en/fr/es/` and keeps `es/` in the captured group.

With my suggested regex we will capture only `en/` in first captured group and next non-capturing group will match `fr/es/` thus giving use `$1=en/` as desired.

Comment: I just didn't understand the `?:`, what is it for?

Comment: hi @anubhava, i'll have one last request please: sometimes i have 2 "/" in my URLs and don't know where they come from (site.com/store//category/)
so how can I alter the rule you gave me so it can redirect the double slashes to the correct URL ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply ;) I'll try it when i'm back home and will let you know ;)

Comment: I have tried: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)/+(/[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]` but site.com/store////// returns  site.com/store// :/

Comment: cool, i found the answer which is yours in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353719/removing-multiple-slashes-with-htaccess) :) thanks again ;)

Comment: Hi @anubhava, I have one other question please, and i prefered to ask it here as you have always gave me great and correct answers :D  
<br/>
I'm using the following directives to hide .php extentions:  
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php`
But it seems like the page is sometimes loaded twice! do you see anything wrong? Thanks a lot

Comment: thanks for your email. I could tell it loads twice because I have a SESSION variable which exists. In the said page (site.com/mypage/) the SESSION variable is unset(). If i do a simple `echo $_SESSION['variable'];` in /mypage/ the variable doesn't show, so it's already unset, but in mypage.php, the SESSION variable is displayed correctly.

Comment: Thank you. It's done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451788/page-loaded-twice-when-hiding-php-extension

Comment: hi @anubhava, hope you're doing well. I remember you were an expert in regex :) would you please be able to contribute in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170921/redirect-urls-that-do-not-start-with-specific-string ? Thank you very much

Comment: Hi again @anubhava, how are you? I'm sorry to bother you, I'm just stuck in a problem and no one seems to be able to help. would you please have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52688593/what-is-wrong-with-this-simple-rewrite-rule-that-doesnt-redirect ?? thanks a lot :)

Comment: Allow me to chase you up again coz i'm blocked because if this said rule that doesn't work, here they are and maybe it'll take you a minute to find what's wrong: 

`RewriteRule ^(?![a-z]{2}/)(.*)$ /en/$1 [R=301,L] # redirect to default language
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]`

Thanks a lot