# Redirect URLs that do not start with specific string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

good day everyone, I'm trying to get a redirection work but i keep getting the error "too many redirects"...
I want to redirect all the URLs that do not start with a specific strings, I wrote this and many others but didn't work:

```
RewriteRule !^(?=string1)(?=string2)(?=string3)/(.*) / [R=301,L]
```

Is there anything wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You should write the pattern as `RewriteRule ^/(?!string1|string2|string3)(.*) / [R=301,L]`. Or `^/(?!(?:string1|string2|string3)/).*`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor for your reply, it almost works perfectly, I had to remove the first "/" but it redirects in loop in the home page. I changed it like this to exclude the home page: `RewriteRule ^(?!/|string1|string2|string3)(.*) / [R=301,L]` but it doesn't really work :/

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^/(?!string1|string2|string3|$)(.*) / [R=301,L]` or, if the first `/` is still a trouble, `RewriteRule ^(?!/string1|/string2|/string3|/$)(.*) / [R=301,L]`

Comment: it still doesn't work with both solutions :(

Comment: Well, if  `^(?!string1|string2|string3).*` (matches any string that does not start with `string1`, `string2` or `string3`) does not work, you need a .htaccess expert help.

Comment: actually it does redirect but the problem is the home page!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude the homepage in your redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!string1|string2|string3|$) / [R=301,L]
```

However, that will not work until you clear your browser cache. When you do that, it will stop redirecting too many times.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I cleared the cache and tried your code, it doesn't redirect in loop for home page, it doesnt redirect the url site.com/string1/mypage/, but it does redirect the url site.com/string2/mypage/ and after the redirect, it appends the querystring: site.com/string2/mypage/ => site.com/?var_name=mypage

Comment: @Websphere This rule will treat both of those paths in the same way. Do you have any other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: you're right, I had to move this rule in the beginning of my htaccess file and everything works like a charm. thanks a lot :) However, it happens that even the 404 errors are being redirected, is there a way to exclude different kind of errors (404, 503, ... )?

Comment: @Websphere You can add a condition for `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}`.